# XSLT - Fill in expected but missing values in an XML file

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt

I have the following XML file that I am parsing with xsltproc:

**Fig1 sheet1.xml**

```
<data>1</data>
<data>2</data>
<data>3</data>
<data>4</data>
```

At certain times I will be receiving data like this

**Fig2 sheet2.xml**

```
<data>1</data>
<data>3</data>
<data>4</data>
```

Currently the data is displayed like this:

a - 1
b - 2
c - 3
d - 4

But with figure 2's data i would get this:
a - 1
b - 2
c - 3
d -

And I want to output data like this:
a - 1
b - NOT EXISTING
c - 3
d - 4

I hope my description of the problem is clear. If you need me to provide more information on my issue -  let me know. Thanks for any help you can provide. I am a beginner so please provide solutions that you think I could implement without too much complication based on the description of my problem.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: In Fig.2 how do you conclude that exactly the second element is missing?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out! I will post my code tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use a recursive template to solve this.